# their or whose?

Tags: pronouns, relative-pronouns

I'd like to know whether I should use "their" or "whose" in the following. And why should I use one over the other?

> Those politicians, whose hands seem to be made to take bribes, and **their**/**whose** lips to tell lies, should be imprisoned till they die.

Comment: *Those politicians, their lips to tell lies, should be imprisoned till they die.* would make no sense

Comment: No grammatical sense, especially. Do you think "whose" is correct? What about replacing "and their lips" in the original with "with their lips"?

Comment: "Those politicians, whose hands seem to be made to take bribes, with their lips to tell lies, should be imprisoned till they die."

Comment: It would break the pattern if you added "with", I am afraid... *"[with] their lips (**[that]** [seem to be made]) to tell lies"*

Comment: *"with their lips (constantly/shamelessly/tirelessly) telling lies"* might work... Although I would stick to "whose" to employ repetition and to seamlessly connect it the previous clause

Comment: Could "with their lips to tell lies" be understood as "with their lips ready to tell lies"?

Answer (score 1):

I think either one is acceptable. Using 'whose' would reuse the word from the first phrase; if you think repetition sounds better, it's there for you. If you don't want to repeat, you have a perfectly good substitute.

Comment: Using "their" would raise the issue of paralelism.